# How to view Statements running with in a function (Greenplum)

Tags: plpgsql, greenplum

Is there any way to find the statements running within a function/procedure in Greenplum like we have "pg_stat_activity" to see queries running in Greenplum databases?

pg_stat_activity only shows the statement which is running/idle etc but not the statements running inside a function if it's running.

is there any other view or tables in Greenplum which have this information?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is currently not visible.

Command Center might give you some insight into actual query processing, but this is not a direct 1:1 relation to what's executed inside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as mentioned by Scherbaum you can't check it. Only workaround is to setting dynamic variable in the function. Like below:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCION test_func()
    AS $$
    DECLARE
        vStep int;
        -- <few other variables>
    BEGIN
        vStep := 1000
            -- <ANY SQL>
        RAISE INFO '%: Completed', vStep
        vStep := 2000
            -- <ANY SQL>
        RAISE INFO '%: Completed', vStep
            -- and so on
    END $$
```

You can check it in your logs on progress.
The above code is just a pseudo code to give a idea, Will not work as it is.